# Categorise JSON data into predefined labels using NLP

Tags: python, python-3.x, nlp, huggingface-transformers

I have an external data vendor that provides me JSON data about some agriculture equipment in some way as format below

```
{
    "EquipmentList": [
        {
            "EquipmentClass": "1",
            "EquipmentID": "1234",  
            "EquipmentGroup": "PLG",
            "Description": "Advanced Electrical Plough, Bosch"
        },
        {
            "EquipmentID": "1235",  
            "EquipmentGroup": "MOT",
            "Description": "Small Gasoline Motor, Honda, 250 kW 1.2L"
        },
        {
            "EquipmentID": "1236",
            "Description": "Leather Grip Handle"
        }
    ]
}
```

Keys `Description` and `EquipmentID` are always present but the other keys are not, as this is based on data harmonisation of the vendor. Now, I have some set of categories that have predefined data type as follows and expected output

| Label Name | Data Type | Expected Output from above |
| --- | --- | --- |
| leatherGrip | bool | true |
| motorSize | float | 1.2 |
| fuelType | str | gasoline |
| ploughType | str | electric |
| ploughVendor | str | Bosch |

I would like this categorisation to be NLP powered as the data contains all sort of vendors that describe their products in different way and string and regex based rules are just too much manual labor intensive to maintain.

I have tried using 4 [Huggingface](https://huggingface.co/) Transformers pre-trained models in zero shot classification pipeline in some way below:

```
from transformers import pipeline
from transformers.utils import logging

logging.set_verbosity_error()
logger = logging.get_logger("transformers")
logger.info("INFO")
logger.warning("WARN")

# model = "bert-base-german-cased"
model = "bert-base-uncased"
# model = "xlm-roberta-base"
# model = "distilbert-base-uncased"
classifier = pipeline("zero-shot-classification", model=model)
possible_plough_motor_vendors = ["Bosch", "Honda", "Shimano", "Volkswagen"]
print("Classification Result: ", classifier(json_src_data[1]["Description"], possible_plough_motor_vendors)
```

The results are as expected highly inaccurate with confidence rates around 3,8% in average. I would love to train own model instead of pre-trained and fine tuned models like BERT which are suitable for long sentences.

What would be best approach/library/platform for my use case? I am very thankful for every constructive feedback.

Comment: It seems to me that you're expecting a bit of magic :) This is apparently a complex task which involves NER and some other logic layer on top. Imho it would require training a custom NER model in order to extract the words which are useful, and this means that somebody would have to manually annotate a representative sample of data. And this would be only the first part.

Comment: Thank you for your input @Erwan. I already have indeed calculated with having to train custom model. I also have a labelled dataset of around 10K data rows. I am not sure how to encode or input this highly nested json data to training algorithm and to be frank not sure what algorithm at all. So I was expecting a friendly nudge in the right direction here.

Comment: Well I don't know much about recent stuff like HuggingFace, but in a traditional ML perspective I think this would start with training a custom [NER model](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Named-entity_recognition), which would require a specific type of annotations inside the description field. In my limited knowledge there's no way to go directly from the input JSON to the expected output.

Comment: thank you, you answered at least one of the questions.